# jqGrid pagination URL with legacy services

Tags: jqgrid

I have legacy services which I have to use for paging and sorting with jqGrid. Is there a way to do it? URL parameters are different from what jqGrid requires and cannot be changed by me.

Comment: Can you please eb a a bit more specific? What do you exactly mean by "URL parameters are different from what jqGrid requires"? Jqgrid produces the url parameters. Also how are you calling the legacy service and what sort of results you get back?

Comment: Service is expecting pagination and sort parameters as part of its JSON request which is POST and are not POST parameters. So instead of having page=1&idx=amount, I have those inside the bigger JSON body. I have to call service using standard AJAX call. It returns JSON which I have to parse to get the table rows. There is no direct mapping from the response to what jqGrid requires.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your JSON result and your jqgrid code?